# Outlook navigation bar control for .NET application

Tags: .net, controls

Is there is an open source or free control like the Outlook Navigation control? I want to add one to my .NET application.

**Update1:**
I am not using WPF. I need control for windows form only and i am using .NET Framework 2.0

Comment: Office Ribbon or Older Office (<2003)? Winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you are looking for a WinForms control.  Here are a couple that I've checked out in the past.

- [Rich OutlookBar in XP and Vista style](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/OutlookBar.aspx)
- [OutlookBar: A Simplified Outlook Style Sidebar Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/OutlookBar.aspx)

Comment: Ah, is there anything you can't get at CodeProject.com? :)

Answer (score 0):

For WPF you can use divelements' SandShell control:

[SandShell for WPF Overview](http://www.divelements.co.uk/net/controls/sandshellwpf/)

*Edit: This is not free, haven't read the question carefully enough.*

Matthias

Comment: No, it's not free. I'm sorry, didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are [several freely available](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=outlook+navigation+control) if you are looking for the older < 2007 version.

If you wanting the 2007 ribbon control, you can use the [WPF Preview](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview), or this [winforms version](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/WinFormsRibbon.aspx).