# UI Designer not in Solution Explorer and unable to get the tool

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

First of all, I am developing an application in VB.NET, till yesterday it was all good. I saved the project and closed it, now when i started working on that application, i found that there was no way to open the UI area for the application. I am able to see the code behind it i.e. on `dashboard.Designer.vb` but not the UI. I am able to see the the application after running it using `F5`. What would be the possible reason for it, and how i can solve it.

---

Secondly, i tried to find search a lot for this tool but unable to get any, if somebody can tell me what tool is this or any similar tool, it would be of great help.

[image: This is the screenshot of the tool, in which i have explained the functionality]

Comment: What happens when you *try* to open the designer? Do you get an error? Does Visual Studio crash? Does it kill your dog? As for your second question (which really should be asked as a separate questions, we don't do 2-in-1 questions here), see here: [Outlook like sidebar and display in Outlook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945837/outlook-like-sidebar-and-display-in-outlook) and [Outlook navigation bar control for .NET application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654536/outlook-navigation-bar-control-for-net-application)

Comment: @CodyGray No nothing happens, everything works just fine. Only i am unable to see any place from where i can see my Form... the UI Form

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you very much for the 2nd question answer, and i'll keep in mind from next time to put different questions for two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for long and found the answer:-

What we need to do is just add the following code in the blank `dashboard.vb` file

```
Public Class dashboard

End Class
```

And this will get the form back.

The second question was answered by @Code Gray
1. [Outlook like sidebar and display in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945837/outlook-like-sidebar-and-display-in-outlook)
2. [Outlook navigation bar control for .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654536/outlook-navigation-bar-control-for-net-application)